# GitHub API - write to repo

Tags: git, api, github

I looked all documentation, but it doesn't answer my question.

There is a way to write to a repo (upload a file)? Something like create a folder, and upload a readme.md

Comment: Pushing using the github api seems quite more complex, then just `git push`. You should read http://developer.github.com/v3/git/ . I suggest you to use `git push` instead, because manipulating the raw `git`-data requires, that you understand gits internals.

Answer (score 1):

Folders do not need to be created as they only exists implicitly in git. Meaning that if you have a file with path `folder/file.txt` then your git client knows to create a folder called "folder" where the file "file.txt" is saved, but to git it is just a file with the name "folder/file.txt"

You can use: `PUT /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}` where `{path}` is the folder path and file name, and put message and file content (Base64 encoded) in the body.

When you are updating a file you also need to indicate which version in the git history of the file you want to update. Read more here https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents