# How to create and update a file in a Github repository with PHP and Github API?

Tags: php, github, github-api

I am trying to build PHP functions to create and update files within a Github repository, using PHP through the Github API.

*The PHP files are being run from a standard shared hosting account. Therefore using frameworks that depend on installing Composer or other libraries is not an option for me. So for example, this https://github.com/KnpLabs/php-github-api is not an option.*

**So far**

I have managed to access and list files using PHP, using the info given here:

[Github API List all repositories and repo's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390090/github-api-list-all-repositories-and-repos-content)

I used a combination of the 2nd and 6th answer (2nd starts with *Here is a nice way just with the curl.* by flesheater and 6th answer with *When you say "display a repo and its contents"* by Ivan Zuzak).

Both list clearly the code and steps needed to list files and get contents (thank you @flesheater and @Ivan Zuzak)

I searched for help or solutions for this. So far I have not found any example, working or otherwise, using PHP.

**Git API documentation**

Git Data API info (https://developer.github.com/v3/git/) says this:

> As an example, if you wanted to commit a change to a file in your
>   repository, you would:
>
> ```
> get the current commit object
> retrieve the tree it points to
> retrieve the content of the blob object that tree has for that particular file path
> change the content somehow and post a new blob object with that new content, getting a blob SHA back
> post a new tree object with that file path pointer replaced with your new blob SHA getting a tree SHA back
> create a new commit object with the current commit SHA as the parent and the new tree SHA, getting a commit SHA back
> update the reference of your branch to point to the new commit SHA
> ```

However there are no code examples of how this is done, and I am not sure if 'commit' is what i need (if I understand correctly, this is not creating a file, only content).

Git Repository API info (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file):

The part 'Create a File' shows a method for doing this, but without code examples. I am usure how to or if this can be used prgrammatically.

### [image: Github API Update a File]

**Similar threads**

In my opinion none are offering enough clarity or information to provide a solution, due to either the questions or answers. Therefore I don't think this is a duplicate.

[How to create a commit and push into repo with GitHub API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801983/how-to-create-a-commit-and-push-into-repo-with-github-api-v3)

This thread has two answers. One is just a link to the Github API which does not give code examples. The other is a Pearl solution (it would seem), but is using a separate Pearlframework.So even trying to convert the Pearl shown is not practical.

[How to create github Repository and upload files from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23152702/how-to-create-github-repository-and-upload-files-from-php)

The answer only repeats the other thread, that a blob should be created. But this is only the very start of what seems to be needed to actually create / update a file through Github API. This thread has a Python example, but that example needs a separate Pearl framework.

[GitHub API - write to repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668283/github-api-write-to-repo/7506554)

This is the thread linked to. It's answered by user who posted a not very clear question, but without any details or clarity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like research paid off and I can answer a main part of my own question (which I was not expecting to be able to do) - creating a new file. It looks like the same approach will be useable to update an exisiting file (if not, I'll be back).

This link helped: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2009/putting-data-fields-with-php-curl

I realised the path referred to in Github API docs (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) - section Create a File - could be used as the url for curl as:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/ USER / REPO_NAME /contents/ FILENAME
```

And some tweaks were needed to allow for JSON to be sent. So I now have:

```
$curl_url = $url
$curl_token_auth = 'Authorization: token ' . $token;
$ch = curl_init($curl_url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'User-Agent: $username', $curl_token_auth ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);

$response = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($response);

return $response;
```

For the $data, I used the JSON example from the Github API page:

```
{
  "message": "my commit message",
  "committer": {
    "name": "Mike A",
    "email": "someemail@gmail.com"
  },
  "content": "bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM="
}
```

After implementing this within a PHP file (on shared hosting), no other frameworks used, I saw the new file in the Github respository.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help to Someone(With SHA feature in addition to update or delete files):

```
<?php
$file_git = "wall.jpg";
$data_git = array(
'sha'=>file_get_contents("sha.txt"),
'message'=>'image',
'content'=> base64_encode($file_git),
'committer'=> array(
'name'=>'Jacob',
'email' => '45331093+greenandgreen@users.noreply.github.com'
)
);
$data_string_git = json_encode($data_git);
$ch_git = curl_init('https://api.github.com/repos/YOUR_REPO/contents/wall.jpg');
curl_setopt($ch_git, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch_git, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string_git);
curl_setopt($ch_git, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch_git, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 YaBrowser/19.9.3.314 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
'Authorization: token PLACE_YOUR_PERSONAL_TOKEN_HERE'
));
$result_git = curl_exec($ch_git);
echo $result_git;
$p_git = json_decode($result_git);
file_put_contents("sha.txt",$p_git->content->sha);
?>
```

Tested on PHP 7.
If the code is working, then I wouldn’t refuse likes, in gratitude for the little work :)

Comment: If someone is struggling with finding how to provide the SHA, here is the example from SDK PHP https://github.com/KnpLabs/php-github-api/blob/master/doc/repo/contents.md#update-a-file

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  function pushFile($username,$token,$repo,$branch,$path,$b64data){
    $message = "Automated update";
    $ch = curl_init("https://api.github.com/repos/$repo/branches/$branch");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent:Php/Automated'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $token);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $data=json_decode($data,1);

    $ch2 = curl_init($data['commit']['commit']['tree']['url']);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent:Php/Ayan Dhara'));
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $token);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $data2 = curl_exec($ch2);
    curl_close($ch2);
    $data2=json_decode($data2,1);

    $sha='';
    foreach($data2["tree"] as $file)
      if($file["path"]==$path)
        $sha=$file["sha"];
    
    $inputdata =[];
    $inputdata["path"]=$path;
    $inputdata["branch"]=$branch;
    $inputdata["message"]=$message;
    $inputdata["content"]=$b64data;
    $inputdata["sha"]=$sha;

    echo json_encode($inputdata);

    $updateUrl="https://api.github.com/repos/$repo/contents/$path";
    echo $updateUrl;
    $ch3 = curl_init($updateUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml', 'User-Agent:Php/Ayan Dhara'));
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $token);
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($inputdata));
    $data3 = curl_exec($ch3);
    curl_close($ch3);

    echo $data3;
  }
  //pushFile("your_username","your_personal_token","username/repository","repository_branch","path_of_targetfile_in_repository","base64_encoded_data");
?>
```

Comment: Please make sure to also add some explanation!

Comment: What more is here to describe ?

Comment: Everything explained in the question I found it works for me so posted it