# How do you convert a Github URL to a file path that a Windows and/or Apple computer could access

Tags: windows, github

I have csv file on a public github repository and I want to be able to access it via a MS Windows or Apple file dialog box. For example, if I want to edit the file in notepad when I click open is ther a way to provide the url so that notepad could access the file on github.

Here is an example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MundyMSDS/DATA607/master/elo_data.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to:

- clone https://github.com/MundyMSDS/DATA607
- edit directly the file you want locally
- add, commit and push

The alternative would be to use the GitHub API, which mainly works to [create a new file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36841665/6309).