# Update github code programatically using php (curl) (no library)

Tags: php, github, github-api

How can I Create, update and delete github code (file) programatically using php (preferably curl) and github api without using any external library ?

I cannot find anything about this. Is this possible or not ?

Comment: If the sever has git on it, you could just have php execute the git commands to do those things directly. Would take a bit of set up with ssh keys etc, but it'd be pretty trivial

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create and update a file in a Github repository with PHP and Github API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835116/how-to-create-and-update-a-file-in-a-github-repository-with-php-and-github-api)

Comment: but it is returning => {"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've resolved it.

```
<?php
  function pushFile($username,$token,$repo,$branch,$path,$b64data){
    $message = "Automated update";
    $ch = curl_init("https://api.github.com/repos/$repo/branches/$branch");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent:Php/Automated'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $token);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $data=json_decode($data,1);

    $ch2 = curl_init($data['commit']['commit']['tree']['url']);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent:Php/Ayan Dhara'));
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $token);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $data2 = curl_exec($ch2);
    curl_close($ch2);
    $data2=json_decode($data2,1);

    $sha='';
    foreach($data2["tree"] as $file)
      if($file["path"]==$path)
        $sha=$file["sha"];
    
    $inputdata =[];
    $inputdata["path"]=$path;
    $inputdata["branch"]=$branch;
    $inputdata["message"]=$message;
    $inputdata["content"]=$b64data;
    $inputdata["sha"]=$sha;

    echo json_encode($inputdata);

    $updateUrl="https://api.github.com/repos/$repo/contents/$path";
    echo $updateUrl;
    $ch3 = curl_init($updateUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml', 'User-Agent:Php/Ayan Dhara'));
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $token);
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($inputdata));
    $data3 = curl_exec($ch3);
    curl_close($ch3);

    echo $data3;
  }
  //pushFile("your_username","your_personal_token","username/repository","repository_branch","path_of_targetfile_in_repository","base64_encoded_data");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the safest/most proper solution would be to use the Github API. You can find the documentation on creating a commit here: https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#create-a-commit

I know you're not wanting to use a library, but this library would probably make this a lot easier: https://packagist.org/packages/knplabs/github-api

If you're not using a library, you'll need to figure out how to make sure your request is properly authenticated: https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication