# Is there a way to push to .MD file on github on a website

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to create a website which will let me log meetings with people. I want it to be able to update a table on a .md file which exists in a github repository each time I click the submit button.

e.g.
In the github repository there will be this table:

| Date | Present | Discussed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19/04/2021 | Tony Stark | Penguins |

And then on a website which I will host on my domain name, I will fill out a form with the content I want to put in the new row. When I click submit, the form will send the data to the .md file and update the table with the content of the new row.

Is there some line of code / querying language which will let me update the table on github when I click the submit button?

Comment: is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36841665/10940544) answer your question?

Comment: It is! Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create and update a file in a Github repository with PHP and Github API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835116/how-to-create-and-update-a-file-in-a-github-repository-with-php-and-github-api)